# SVN: unknown host Eclipse Juno for local internal servers

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, ubuntu-12.04, subclipse

I am using Ubuntu, eclipse juno and subclipse 1.6x. When i tried to connect to our local svn server, its always throwing the error "SVN: Unknown host"

Its working normal with other svn links which i taken from the Google code.

I need some one's advice to rectify this immediately. Thanks.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution? I'm suddenly having the same problem

Comment: I forgot I had to change to our guest network this morning so when I changed to our secured network I got in. So, probably not the same problem